# Hangman While loop solution

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class Hangman 
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter word: ");
    String Word = kybd.nextLine();
    String dashWord = Word.replaceAll(".", "-");
    System.out.println(dashWord);

    StringBuilder dashWordB = new StringBuilder(dashWord);

    System.out.println("Please guess a letter: ");
    char letterGuess = kybd.next().charAt(0);
    int lettersGuessed = 0;

// While loop should exit once letterGuessed is equal to Word.length()

 while (lettersGuessed <= Word.length()){
       for (int i=0; i < Word.length(); i++)
    {

       if (Word.charAt(i) == letterGuess)
            {
            dashWordB.setCharAt(i,letterGuess);
            lettersGuessed++;
            System.out.println("letters guessed: " + lettersGuessed);
                System.out.println("word length: " + Word.length());
            }
       if (i == Word.length() - 1)
       {
           i = -1;
           System.out.println(dashWordB);
           System.out.println("Have another guess: ");
           letterGuess = kybd.next().charAt(0);
        }

     }
 }
    System.out.println(dashWordB);
    System.out.println(lettersGuessed);

   }          
 }
```

Having trouble exiting while loop when all letters of dashWordB are guessed correctly. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `while (lettersGuessed <= Word.length())` will only exit once `lettersGuessed` is *greater* than `Word.length()`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following in your while loop:

```
if(lettersGuessed == Word.length()){
    break;
}
```

That should help you fix the problem.

Also as suggested by the others change the while condition to the following:

```
while (lettersGuessed < Word.length())
```

So your while loop should be the following:

```
while (lettersGuessed < Word.length()){
        for (int i=0; i < Word.length(); i++)
        {

            if (Word.charAt(i) == letterGuess)
            {
                dashWordB.setCharAt(i,letterGuess);
                lettersGuessed++;
                System.out.println("letters guessed: " + lettersGuessed);
                System.out.println("word length: " + Word.length());
            }
            if (i == (Word.length() - 1))
            {
                i = -1;
                System.out.println(dashWordB);
                System.out.println("Have another guess: ");
                letterGuess = kybd.next().charAt(0);
            }

            if(lettersGuessed == Word.length()){
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: `while (lettersGuessed <= Word.length()){`

You will exit only if `lettersGuessed > Word.length()` or if you guessed correctly a letter more than the length of the word.

Try `while (lettersGuessed < Word.length()){`

Comment: i have changed it, although it still continues to output "have another guess" even when i repeat a letter and the lettersGuessed goes over the word.length()

Comment: Your 'if (i == Word.length() - 1)' should be worked on and removed of the for loop to get the result that you want.